# Python Script as Web page

Tags: python, html, web

I have a python notebook script; here I have a hard-coded text which I process and display as a tabular format. 
What I am looking is to host this my local web so that others too can access this via their PC. 
Need help/suggestions.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Comment: If you actually want to serve a notebook file, look into JupyterHub or the Jupyter documentation on public servers (because Jupyter is already a web server running Tornado framework, listed above)

Answer (score 0):

Flask =) http://flask.pocoo.org/. And locally hosting I use WAMP.